# How to give $_SESSION value based on what visitor does in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm having this nasty problem that I can't find an answer to. Basically I have multiple forms on my php page. I need to pass $_SESSION value based on which form visitor uses.

For example, if he uses one form, I need these values

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['socnetwork'] = '1';
    $_SESSION['cost'] = '15';
    $_SESSION['soccount'] = '100';
```

If he uses another form on that page, I need different values to be passed on submit="somepage.php", for example

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['socnetwork'] = '2';
    $_SESSION['cost'] = '55';
    $_SESSION['soccount'] = '700';
```

How would you recommend me to approach this? Variables need to be secure! I cannot pass them in URL, although this would be so convinient.

Comment: Can't you use an if statement to determine the course of action?

Comment: So are the values being assigned to `$_SESSION` hardcoded or are they being POSTed?

Comment: Nop. All forms are visible on the page, and I need to pass _SESSION values based on which form is chosen and submited

Comment: hard cored. I could try post actually, but then its easy to edit HTTP requests and mess with them

Comment: Maybe you can add info to the $session cookie from javascript on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client-side, you may use an `if` statement (you would need JavaScript in this case) and send the required information to PHP server-side using a [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

On the server-side, you may create a handling code, which will set the required values to the `$_SESSION` variable.

Alternatively, if the values are fixed, you could send not the values but rather some integer or string code from client side to the server side (it could be done with plain HTML), and then use an `if` statement on the server-side (PHP in your case). In this case, that is also possible to insert the numbers to the HTML form with PHP like that:

```
<input type='hidden' name="category" value=" <?php echo $some_code; ?> " />
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I'll do something similar to your 3rd suggesstion, since I'm a total PHP noob and cannt even realy understand other suggestions :(. I think I'll just add some randomized cookie that will be decoded on other page

Comment: Actually _post would do better i guess

Comment: Sure, post is a very suitable technology in your case!

Answer (score 0):

You may store arrays in sessions so make somethings like `$_SESSION['custom_pages']` where each key is the name of page (or id) and values - are arrays of 'socnetwork', 'cost',..

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form1'] = ['socnetwork'> = '1',
                     'cost' => '15',
                     'soccount' => '100];
....
....
$_SESSION['form2'] = ['socnetwork'> = '2',
                     'cost' => '55',
                     'soccount' => '700];
```

Answer (score 0):

A submit button adds its name to the `$_POST` button, so if you name your buttons you know which button the visitor used.

E.g

```
<form action="somepage.php">
    <input type="submit" name="form1" value="Submit!">
</form>

<form action="somepage.php">
    <input type="submit" name="form2" value="Submit other form!">
</form>

<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

would give

> array(1) { ["form1"]=> string(7) "Submit!" }
>
> array(1) { ["form2"]=> string(18) "Submit other form!" }

And from that point it is a matter of checking whether a certain key exists.